# Table(Model) Inheritance with Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed the advice in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337095/sqlalchemy-inheritance) but I'm still receiving this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'investment' and 'real_estate'.`

**Models**

```
class Investment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'investment'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'investment'}

    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_name = Column(db.String(64))
    investment_type = Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': investment_type}

class RealEstate(Investment):

    __tablename__ = 'real_estate'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'real_estate'}
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    current_balance = Column(db.Float)
```

I also updated the examples in that answer to reflect changes in SQLAlchemy's docs but, still, the error.

The **goal** here is that I don't want the attributes inherited by RealEstate to be in the Investment table. I would like to inherit and retain all of these attributes with the RealEstate table.

Can anyone see what I missed?

Comment: This might be of interest for others: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` attribute in RealEstate must be a foreign key referencing the Investment. Otherwise, how can you say that every RealEstate is an investment ?

Change your RealEstate class definition to the following:

```
class RealEstate(Investment):
    __tablename__ = 'real_estate'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'real_estate'}
    # This id below should reference Investment. Hence, define it as foreign key. 
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('investment.id'), primary_key=True)
    current_balance = Column(db.Float)
```

Comment: This did not work for me, the only way I could create the table without getting an error was by changing the id column to the following:

`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)`.  If anybody comes across this comment and can tell me why, even with the code exactly as above I was unable to generate a primary key without that default, please let me know.