# When do I need to use sqlalchemy back_populates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I try SQLAlchemy Relation Example following this guide: [Basic Relationship Patterns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many)

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent")

Base.metadata.create_all()

p = Parent()
session.add(p)
session.commit()
c = Child(parent_id=p.id)
session.add(c)
session.commit()
print "children: {}".format(p.children[0].id)
print "parent: {}".format(c.parent.id)
```

It works well, but in the guide, it says the model should be:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    **children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")**

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    **parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")**
```

Why don't I need `back_populates` or `backref` in my example?  When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

If you use `backref` you don't need to declare the relationship on the second table.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

If you're *not* using `backref`, and defining the `relationship`'s separately, then if you don't use `back_populates`, sqlalchemy won't know to connect the relationships, so that modifying one also modifies the other.

So, in your example, where you've defined the `relationship`'s separately, but didn't provide a `back_populates` argument, modifying one field wouldn't automatically update the other in your transaction.

```
>>> parent = Parent()
>>> child = Child()
>>> child.parent = parent
>>> print(parent.children)
[]
```

See how it didn't automatically fill out the `children` field?

Now, if you supply a `back_populates` argument, sqlalchemy will connect the fields.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

So now we get

```
>>> parent = Parent()
>>> child = Child()
>>> child.parent = parent
>>> print(parent.children)
[Child(...)]
```

Sqlalchemy knows these two fields are related now, and will update each as the other is updated.  It's worth noting that using `backref` will do this, too.  Using `back_populates` is nice if you want to define the relationships on every class, so it's easy to see all the fields just be glancing at the model class, instead of having to look at other classes that define fields via backref.

Comment: A note about `back_populates` vs `backref`: `backref` is more succinct because you don't need to declare the relation on both classes, but in practice I find it not worth to save this on line. I think `back_populates` is better, not only because in python culture _"Explicit is better than implicit"_ (Zen of Python), but when you have many models, with a quick glance at its declaration you can see all relationships and their names instead of going over all related models. Also, a nice side benefit of `back_populates` is that you get auto-complete on both directions on most IDEs =)

Comment: backref may seem easier to implement (especially If you clearly indicate the relationship in both classes using comments, at least I thought so...), until you need to implement multiple relationships to a single table and work with containers. In the end back_populates makes your code easier to understand

Comment: is the `parent_id` really necessary under Child?
And what about helper tables, as indicated [in the documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @LuizTauffer The `parent_id` is the actual foreign key field that stores the parent-child relationship. It is necessary. Helper tables are for defining many-to-many relationships (for example, if a Child could have more than one Parent). The fkey example above is the classical one-to-manay example where each Child has one and only one Parent, and a parent can have many Children.

Comment: if you need to retrieve information from one side only, you can add back_populates only on the given side. Example you can have back_populates on the children which will provide info about the parent, and leave the parent class not 'back_populated' with children references

Comment: All great answers here. Just to add something which I didn't see mentioned; with `back_populates` I started running into circular dependency issues as the project grew. So using `backref` where the entity is needed only at one end helps reduce the chances of running into dependencies.

Comment: @BrendanAbel Hi Brendan what if both tables are circular reference? That is parent table has a FK that references to child table and child table has a FK references to parent table. In this case, for instance, there is a status column in parent table that whenever it changes, it will be logged in the child table. This is a one-to-many circular reference relationship. How do I access the child table from the parent table in this case?

Comment: @J_Y Those sound like two unrelated relationships, is that correct?

Comment: @BrendanAbel they are related relationships would you be okay if I tag you in my post as I have posted a question regards to this

Comment: The relationship.backref parameter is generally considered to be legacy.for modern applications, using explicit relationship() constructs linked together using the relationship.back_populates parameter should be preferred. See documentation https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref

Comment: For anyone concerned about circular dependencies, you won't have any issues if you reference the related classes via their strings e.g. `"Parent"` and `"Child"` like in the question here since you don't need to import in that case. It's only an issue if you try to use the classes directly e.g. `Parent` and `Child`.