# SQL Alchemy One to One (Flask)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to make a profile for user in one to one relationships tables. How can i do it for User, and User's profile.

Also i want to show join them together.. How can i join profile and users table for CRUD operations.

Thank you so much..

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default = False)
    token = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True)
    profile = relationship("Profile", lazy = "joined")

    def __init__(self, email, password, token, is_admin = False, is_active = False):
        self.email = email
        self.password = self.GenerateHash(password)
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.is_admin = is_admin
        self.token = token
```

class Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line in the **User** table:

```
profile = relationship("Profile", lazy = "joined")
```

by

```
profile = relationship("Profile", uselist=False, back_populates="users")
```

and in the **Profile** class:

```
class Profile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'profiles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="profiles")
```

You can check the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)

Edit: as there is no specification about the class **Profile** I change the superclass of it as *db.Model*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What is the meaning of back_populates in relationships?

Comment: It is used to let know sqlalchemy the connection between both tables, you can avoid it by using  `backref` instead. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870250) is a good explanation.