# Concepts of backref and back_populate in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Can anyone explain the concepts of these two ideas and how they relate to making relationships between tables? I can't really seem to find anything that explains it clearly and the documentation feels like there's too much jargon to understand in easy concepts. For instance, in this example of a one to many relationship in the documentation:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

Why does the `relationship()` go inside the parent class while `ForeignKey` goes inside the child class? And what does having `back_populates` exactly do to one another? Does having the placement of which class the `relationship()` function exist in matter?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I need to use sqlalchemy back\_populates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869793/when-do-i-need-to-use-sqlalchemy-back-populates)

Comment: "there's too much jargon to understand in easy concepts", well said

Comment: As of July 2022, `backref` is considered legacy and `back_populates` is preferred.

Comment: I agree that the documentation is absurdly jargon-heavy.

Comment: @GordThompson, but the current documentation recommends both without mention of one being preferred over the other, implying that they have different purposes: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html

Comment: @Stonecraft - We are in the process of updating the documentation, e.g., [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html)

Answer (score 172):

`backref` is a shortcut for configuring both `parent.children` and `child.parent` `relationship`s at one place only on the parent or the child class (not both). That is, instead of having

```py
children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")  # on the parent class
```

and

```py
parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")  # on the child class
```

you only need one of this:

```py
children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")  # only on the parent class
```

or

```py
parent = relationship("Parent", backref="children")  # only on the child class
```

`children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")` will create the `.parent` relationship on the child class automatically. On the other hand, if you use `back_populates` you **must** explicitly create the `relationship`s in both parent and child classes.

**Why does the relationship() go inside the parent class while ForeignKey goes inside the child class?**

As I said above, if you use `back_populates`, it needs to go on both parent and child classes. If you use `backref`, it needs to go on one of them only. `ForeignKey` needs to go on the child class, no matter where the `relationship` is placed, this is a fundamental concept of relational databases.

**And what does having back_populates exactly do to one another?**

`back_populates` informs each relationship about the other, so that they are kept in sync. For example if you do

```py
p1 = Parent()
c1 = Child()
p1.children.append(c1)
print(p1.children)  # will print a list of Child instances with one element: c1
print(c1.parent)  # will print Parent instance: p1
```

As you can see, `p1` was set as parent of `c1` even when you didn't set it explicitly.

**Does having the placement of which class the relationship() function exist in matter?**

This only applies to `backref`, and no, you can place the relationship on the parent class (`children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")`) or on the child class (`parent = relationship("Parent", backref="children")`) and have the exact same effect.

Comment: Placing backref decides the "one" side of the one-to-many relationship doesn't it?

Comment: Which is better practice currently? I kinda like backref only cos it reads better in a way...

Comment: @Zaffer Back_populates is actually better to understand, because you see on both tables what their relationships are. If you only use backref, you won't see what other tables relate to the parent if you had it declared only on the child and vice versa.

Comment: @Zaffer re: "Which is better practice currently?" - As of July 2022, `backref` is [considered legacy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html) and `back_populates` is preferred.

Comment: @GordThompson THIS! This is gold! The anwer above is very helpful, and your conclusion is the great final touch!

Comment: That's what it does? What is `back_populates` "populating"? It's not moving data around, is it? Isn't it just maintain a reference between two models?

Comment: @eRunner Maybe you could rephrase this sentence: "Does having the placement of which class the relationship() function exist in matter?"

Answer (score 17):

Apparently, use of `back_populates` with explicit `relationship()` constructs should be preferred as explained at:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html

Comment: Yes. It also makes it easier to understand the code when the relations are defined on both the parent and child models.