# back_populates behaviour in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

As explained in the answer of [When do I need to use sqlalchemy back_populates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869793/when-do-i-need-to-use-sqlalchemy-back-populates) question, in SQLAlchemy you can define a related field in **both** of the classes to be *explicit* by using the parameter `back_populates` referring to the other variable name instead of the Django way of defining in one side and *implicitly* be defined in the other end by using the `related_name` or the default value `<classname>_set`
I like that way because it follow the principle of the Python Zen *better explicit than implicit*.
The question is how to write this code

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")  # Parent.children <--o2o--> Child.parent

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")  # Child.parent <--o2o--> Parent.children
```

in `Django >= 3`.

Comment: In Django you don't need to do a `back_populates`, it already has a `related_name` that automatically adds the relation in reverse.

Comment: I know, but I don't like that way because if you have many class variables you may forget some of them. I like to use the class definition for documentation, do you know any way to do that?

Comment: you don't. Furthermore it is not necessary, and conflicts another principle **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself (DRY). In fact you can just use the `_meta` options to find out the relations of a model object.

Comment: you can also simply add a line of comment in your model that specifies the backref. Furthermore if you for example use PyCharm with the Django support (paid edition), then the IDE includes these relations in the autocomplete.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go. Thank you for that PyCharm tip although I use VSCode.