# issue creating one to many relationships with sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

need some help with creating relationship using databases pypi
https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/

other helpful link https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

here i want a user in `users` table to be able to create many notes from `notes` table, so one-to-many for one user to many notes

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, DateTime, MetaData, Sequence, ForeignKey

metadata = MetaData()

users = Table(
    "users", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, Sequence("users_id_seq"), primary_key=True),
    Column("email", String(254), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True),
    Column("phone_number", String(32)),
    Column("password", String(128), nullable=False),
    relationship("notes", back_populates = "notes"),


notes = Table(
    "notes", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, Sequence("notes_id_seq"), primary_key=True),
    Column("text", String(length=100)),
    Column("completed", Boolean),
)
```

but i get error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <RelationshipProperty at 0x7f292b56be40; no key>
```

How do i create this relationship correctly?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and has syntax errors - the error you shared is indicating you are passing a relationship where something like a column or constraint was expected.

Comment: isn't that why am seeking help?

Comment: here is documentation i followed https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/ please read question and try to be helpful rather than condemning things

Comment: Syntax errors are pointed out by any editor worth using and if you make mistakes copying and pasting code from some site and just post the result on StackOverflow, it's clear you didn't put in a lot of effort to try and resolve it - please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at the very least get rid of simple typos.

Comment: Also, please note that you took an example about creating basic tables and simply pasted in a line from another example that is about creating relationships through ORM - have a look at questions like these to see what you should be doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869793/when-do-i-need-to-use-sqlalchemy-back-populates

Comment: You are using SQLAlchemy core.  Relationships are part of the SQLAlchemy ORM layer, you can't use them in the core layer.

Comment: so what do i do here? i just want to be able to add relationships to what i have